# Formula for possible delta wave

Tags: probability-theory, wave-equation

I would like to know whether there is any formula that would help me compute the number of possible delta waves from `(0,0) to (N,0)`.

eg. for `N = 4`, we have `number of waves possible = 9` as explained [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nankP.jpg)

Comment: I think you are asking for how many sequences of 1s and -1s and 0s summing to zero and with a given length exist. That is a more familiar way to frame it. Put that way, you need to have as many 1s as -1s and can have any number of 0s...

Comment: Maybe @Ian. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: It looks like we have an additional constraint that the sum cannot be negative at any point (the wave cannot go below $y=0$).

Comment: Did you get the image from wikipedia? There is a formula (involving a summation) there. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motzkin_number

Comment: I missed the non negativity constraint; that complicates matters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A mouse leaping along the square tile](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150420/a-mouse-leaping-along-the-square-tile) ...and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1205808/on-an-h-times-h-square-lattice-count-all-the-paths-from-0-a-to-h-1-b) is a more general duplicate.

Comment: Thanks everyone for pointing me in the right direction.